# Flask socketio not emitting event in dash callback

Tags: python, flask, socket.io

`socketio.emit('text', 'text')` not working inside **dash callback** where we write something back to the database.

These same emit is working inside other callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Flask socket io stalls when there are long polling processes. We need to emit before the start of such processes otherwise there is no impact of the emit statement. Just emitting before writing to the db fixed the issue.